# what's the difference between Ausstellungsdatum und Erteilungsdatum?

Tags: translation

Können Sie bitte mir sagen, was der Unterschied zwischen "Ausstellungsdatum" und "Erteilungsdatum" ist?

Comment: Kontext wäre gut, sowie eine Übersicht, was die eigene Recherche erbracht hat, und wieso das die Frage nicht beantwortet hat.

Comment: Welche Informationen hast du bereits durch das Konsultieren von Suchmaschinen erhalten? Was genau war daran unklar? Davon abgesehen glaube ich, dass auch in Ländern mit anderen Amtssprachen vergleichbare Begriffe verwendet werden, so dass ich keinen direkten Zusammenhang mit der deutschen Sprache sehe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erteilungsdatum bezieht sich eher auf eine Genehmigung. Beispiel: Ich habe die Baugenehmigung erteilt bekommen.
Ausstellungsdatum bezieht sich dann auf ein Dokument, was man ausgehändigt bekommt. Beispiel: Das Ausstellungsdatum meines Personalausweises ist der 10.12.2017.

Answer (score 2):

Es geht um den Unterschied z.B. zwischen dem Bestehen einer Erlaubnis und dem Besitz eines Dokumentes, das diese Erlaubnis bestätigt.

Verliert man das Dokument, besteht die Erlaubnis weiterhin. Man kann das bloß nicht mehr so einfach nachweisen. Geht man zum Amt und beantragt man ein Ersatzdokument, so steht auf dem Ersatzdokument dasselbe Datum für das Bestehen der Erlaubnis wie auf dem Originaldokument. Das Ausstellungsdatum ist aber das Datum, zu dem das Ersatzdokument erstellt wurde.

Comment: Danke schön für die Hilfe!